# Check react input form for decimals and change value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, numbers, decimal

In my current React application, I need an Input which validates and changes the outcome on the following rules:

```
Input: 10 -> Output: 1000
Input: 10.5 -> Output: 1050
Input: 10.55 -> Output: 1055
```

This is what I have so far:

```
<Form.Control
    as="input"
    type="number"
    min="0.00"
    step=".01"
    onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
/>
```

```
handleChange(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    if(event.target.value.includes('.')) {
        let values = event.target.value.split('.')
        if(values[1].length <= 1) {
            let decimal = values[1] = values[1] + '0';
            let output = values[0] + decimal;
        }
    }
    this.submitPayment(output) // error: output not defined
}
```

My problem is right now that my code only works if a decimal (point/comma) is entered.

Also I guess there is a much more "elegant" solution for this, which would be great to know!

Comment: Can't you simply multiply input by 100?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you simply don't do that:

```
handleChange(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    const output = parseFloat(event.target.value) * 100
    this.submitPayment(output);
}
```